# If row below duplicate, use value from other columns until a new value is found

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a tricky data manipulation question. Basically, I have a list of dates. On each day, there is a count of how many issues are open. I want to create a new column, `ideal_issues_left`, that uses `np.linspace` to calculate the ideal number of issues left, if they are all to be completed at a steady rate each day to zero at the end of the date range.

I have managed to create a dataframe of the estimates per day from each starting point, but what I want to do now is fill the `ideal_issues_left` column with the estimates based on the following logic:

1. If the number of open issues is different the next day, fill `ideal_issues_left` with the first column from the estimates data frame.
2. If the number of open issues is the same, fill `ideal_issues_left` with data from the columns 1+, until a new number of `open_issues` is reached.

For example, say this is the date range and open issues:

```
import pandas as pd

chart_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-08-19', '2018-09-01', freq='d'),
    'open_issues': [23.0, 25.0, 26.0, 26.0, 28.0, 36.0, 33.0, 39.0, 39.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0]
})

chart_data
         date  open_issues
0  2020-08-19         23.0
1  2020-08-20         25.0
2  2020-08-21         26.0
3  2020-08-22         26.0
4  2020-08-23         28.0
5  2020-08-24         36.0
6  2020-08-25         33.0
7  2020-08-26         39.0
8  2020-08-27         39.0
9  2020-08-28         38.0
10 2020-08-29         38.0
11 2020-08-30         38.0
12 2020-08-31         38.0
13 2020-09-01         38.0
```

```
p = []
for day, val in enumerate(chart_data.loc[:, 'open_issues']):
                days_left = 14 - day
                p.append(np.linspace(start=val, stop=0, num=days_left))

estimates = pd.DataFrame(p)
estimates
      0          1          2          3          4          5          6          7         8         9         10        11        12   13
0   23.0  21.230769  19.461538  17.692308  15.923077  14.153846  12.384615  10.615385  8.846154  7.076923  5.307692  3.538462  1.769231  0.0
1   25.0  22.916667  20.833333  18.750000  16.666667  14.583333  12.500000  10.416667  8.333333  6.250000  4.166667  2.083333  0.000000  NaN
2   26.0  23.636364  21.272727  18.909091  16.545455  14.181818  11.818182   9.454545  7.090909  4.727273  2.363636  0.000000       NaN  NaN
3   26.0  23.400000  20.800000  18.200000  15.600000  13.000000  10.400000   7.800000  5.200000  2.600000  0.000000       NaN       NaN  NaN
4   28.0  24.888889  21.777778  18.666667  15.555556  12.444444   9.333333   6.222222  3.111111  0.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
5   36.0  31.500000  27.000000  22.500000  18.000000  13.500000   9.000000   4.500000  0.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
6   33.0  28.285714  23.571429  18.857143  14.142857   9.428571   4.714286   0.000000       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
7   39.0  32.500000  26.000000  19.500000  13.000000   6.500000   0.000000        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
8   39.0  31.200000  23.400000  15.600000   7.800000   0.000000        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
9   38.0  28.500000  19.000000   9.500000   0.000000        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
10  38.0  25.333333  12.666667   0.000000        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
11  38.0  19.000000   0.000000        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
12  38.0   0.000000        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
13  38.0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
```

The desired end result should be:

```
chart_data
         date  open_issues ideal_issues_left
0  2018-08-19         23.0    23.0
1  2018-08-20         25.0    25.0
2  2018-08-21         26.0    26.0 # <- this value is from estimates row 2 col 0
3  2018-08-22         26.0    23.6 # <- this value is from estimates row 2 col 1
4  2018-08-23         28.0    28.0
5  2018-08-24         36.0    36.0
6  2018-08-25         33.0    33.0
7  2018-08-26         39.0    39.0 # <- this value is from estimates row 7 col 0
8  2018-08-27         39.0    32.5 # <- this value is from estimates row 7 col 1
9  2018-08-28         38.0    38.0 # <- this value is from estimates row 9 col 0
10 2018-08-29         38.0    28.5 # <- this value is from estimates row 9 col 1
11 2018-08-30         38.0    19.0 # <- this value is from estimates row 9 col 2
12 2018-08-31         38.0    9.5  # <- this value is from estimates row 9 col 3
13 2018-09-01         38.0    0.0  # <- this value is from estimates row 9 col 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are an equal number of issues, the cumulative count is taken from the sum of the cumulative total. The value is updated with the data extracted in the same number of issues in the reference data frame.

```
chart_data['flg'] = chart_data['open_issues'].groupby(((chart_data['open_issues'] != chart_data['open_issues'].shift())).cumsum()).cumcount()
chart_data
    date    open_issues flg
0   2018-08-19  23.0    0
1   2018-08-20  25.0    0
2   2018-08-21  26.0    0
3   2018-08-22  26.0    1
4   2018-08-23  28.0    0
5   2018-08-24  36.0    0
6   2018-08-25  33.0    0
7   2018-08-26  39.0    0
8   2018-08-27  39.0    1
9   2018-08-28  38.0    0
10  2018-08-29  38.0    1
11  2018-08-30  38.0    2
12  2018-08-31  38.0    3
13  2018-09-01  38.0    4

for i,issues in enumerate(chart_data['open_issues']):
    k = chart_data.loc[i,'flg']
    df = estimates[estimates[0] == issues]
    l = df.iloc[:1, k].values
#     print(l)
    chart_data.loc[i,'idea_issues_left'] = l

chart_data
    date    open_issues flg idea_issues_left
0   2018-08-19  23.0    0   23.000000
1   2018-08-20  25.0    0   25.000000
2   2018-08-21  26.0    0   26.000000
3   2018-08-22  26.0    1   23.636364
4   2018-08-23  28.0    0   28.000000
5   2018-08-24  36.0    0   36.000000
6   2018-08-25  33.0    0   33.000000
7   2018-08-26  39.0    0   39.000000
8   2018-08-27  39.0    1   32.500000
9   2018-08-28  38.0    0   38.000000
10  2018-08-29  38.0    1   28.500000
11  2018-08-30  38.0    2   19.000000
12  2018-08-31  38.0    3   9.500000
13  2018-09-01  38.0    4   0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is large and you want to avoid looping you can use `merge` instead.

```
chart_data["prev_day_open_issues"] = chart_data["open_issues"].shift(1)
chart_data["no match"] = chart_data["open_issues"] != chart_data["prev_day_open_issues"]
# same idea as in r-beginners code
chart_data["ideal_pos"] = (chart_data["open_issues"]
  .groupby(chart_data["no match"].cumsum())
  .cumcount())

# tidy up and remove temp columns
new_chart_data = chart_data[["date", "open_issues", "ideal_pos"]]

# make your estimates dataframe into a one-to-one lookup in long format
estimates["open_issues"] = estimates[0]
new_estimates = (estimates
                 .drop_duplicates(subset=["open_issues"])
                 .melt(id_vars="open_issues", var_name="ideal_pos", 
                       value_name="ideal_issues_left"))

# join
final = new_chart_data.merge(new_estimates, how="left", on=["open_issues", "ideal_pos"])

print(final[["date", "open_issues", "ideal_issues_left"]])


      date  open_issues  ideal_issues_left
2018-08-19         23.0          23.000000
2018-08-20         25.0          25.000000
2018-08-21         26.0          26.000000
2018-08-21         26.0          23.636364
2018-08-23         28.0          28.000000
2018-08-24         36.0          36.000000
2018-08-25         33.0          33.000000
2018-08-26         39.0          39.000000
2018-08-26         39.0          32.500000
2018-08-28         38.0          38.000000
2018-08-28         38.0          28.500000
2018-08-28         38.0          19.000000
2018-08-28         38.0           9.500000
2018-08-28         38.0           0.000000
```